# Xamarin ios map circle overlay click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm following the maps example https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/map/circle/ to create custom renderer to overlay circles. It seems to be working fine for all 3 platforms except I am unable to find any click event for iOS.

I am building a xamarin forms app and able to find out the click event on both Android and UWP but iOS seems to be far fetched.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean the click on the pin or the circle? The click on pin works perfectly on my side.

Comment: Click on the circle, i dont have any pins on the map. Clicking on the circle works fine on android and uwp but ios doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't provide the API which detects the click event.

As a alternative workaround, we can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the mapview and judge if the tap point locates inside the circle.

#### Solution

```
//xxx
nativeMap.AddOverlay(circleOverlay);
nativeMap.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(TapHandle));

void TapHandle(UITapGestureRecognizer tap)
{
    MKMapView mapView = tap.View as MKMapView;

    CGPoint tapPoint = tap.LocationInView(mapView);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D tapCoordinate = mapView.ConvertPoint(tapPoint, tap.View);
    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPoint.FromCoordinate(tapCoordinate);

    foreach(IMKOverlay overlay in mapView.Overlays)
    {
        MKCircleRenderer render = GetOverlayRenderer(mapView, overlay) as MKCircleRenderer;
        CGPoint datPoint = render.PointForMapPoint(point);
        render.InvalidatePath();

        if (render.Path.ContainsPoint(datPoint,false))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```